# Apache VHost localhost not working on OSX

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, localhost, virtualhost

I've had VHosts working on my OSX client for quite some time. Recently, I've been trying to use `http://localhost` to access the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` but it keeps redirecting my to my blog. Can anyone point me in the direction where I might be going wrong?

Here is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 

127.0.0.1 www.chrislrobinson.co.uk
127.0.0.1 blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk
```

And here is my `httpd.conf` file:

```
...
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And finally here is my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/blog>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/chrislrobinson>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/blog"
    ServerName blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/chrislrobinson"
    ServerName www.chrislrobinson.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents
    ServerName www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your host specification on the localhost block; it needs to match the `NameVirtualHost` directive.  (There should be a warning in your error log when apache starts about this)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Since having it on your default port listener will probably be exposing it to the internet (only with a host header of `localhost`, but still..), consider locking it down, too:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I had tried that combination but I guess I had something else going wrong with it!